# pipenv shell working but an error is displayed

Tags: python-3.x, bash, pipenv

If I run the command:

```
pipenv shell
```

in my Mac shell, everything works fine and a new virtual environment is created and activated:

```
.../django_celery_rabbit_flower$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
.../django_celery_rabbit_flower$  . /.../django_celery_rabbit_flower-rEt8HW1V/bin/activate
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
(django_celery_rabbit_flower) .../django_celery_rabbit_flower$
```

but a bash error is displayed:

```
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

I do not understand where it come from. Any idea?

UPDATE

Jen answer trigger a little thought. I have checked my ./bash_profile and I can see the line:

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\$ "
```

This shows the git branch on the bash prompt. So I believe vscode uses this settings. The folder I am working on is not a git folder. Can I write an if statement to avoid the error being displayed when running the python virtual environment?

Comment: Could be a PATH problem. At your shell prompt, what does `which parse_git_branch` say?

Comment: Hi Jen, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. which parse_git_branch do not return anything

Comment: @Jens -- `which` (in bash, unlike zsh) is not _expected_ to say anything; as an external command it doesn't know about functions, aliases, etc, so all it can do is search the PATH. `type parse_git_branch` has a higher chance of being useful.

Comment: @Dino, chances are you have a shell function that needs to be `export`ed. If your PS1 is in the environment (which it is because the command uses `export`), subprocesses inherit it; but functions _aren't_ exported unless one explicitly exports them with `export -f`. So after whatever code defines the `parse_git_branch` function, you need `export -f parse_git_branch`.

Comment: A few issues: first, `PS1` does not need to be exported, and should be defined in `.bashrc`. Second, `.bash_profile` should source `.bashrc`, since it is executed *instead* of `.bashrc` for a login shell. (`zsh`, by the way, is little more sensible, sourcing `.zshrc` for *all* interactive shells, not just non-login shells). Finally, `parse_git_branch` is likely a shell function that doesn't get defined by an ordinary interactive shell (and functions aren't inherited, like your `PS1` variable currently is); check `.bash_profile` to see if it defines the function, or sources a file that does.

Comment: Hi Charles, your solution worked. If you put your comment in a proper answer, I am happy to vote for it. Thank you to everyone has taken the time to respond to my my question

Answer (score 1):

Instead make sure that the command does actually exists before running it.

```
PS1="...."'$(if hash parse_git_branch >/dev/null 2>&1; then parse_git_branch; fi)'"..."
```

Comment: Or the OP could just stop `export`ing their PS1 so subprocesses that don't have the necessary shell functions to use it successfully no longer see it at all.